# How can I add a light switch to an existing lighting circuit?

Tags: electrical, switch

I have a Light switch that runs four lights, I would like to add a switch to the last light. Is this possible and how could this be wired?

Comment: Do you want the 4th light to be controlled only by the new switch, leaving the old switch to control only the first 3 lights?  Or do you want both switches to control the 4th light?  If the latter is your desire, could you explain whether you want the light to be on or off for each of the four possible combinations of two switches controlling it?

Comment: Based on you're question, I assume that you are going to have to run new wire. How it needs to be run, and how many wires in the cable is hard to say, because you're question isn't specific enough.

Answer (score 3):

Anything can be done, but in simple terms, NO you cannot switch one light that is already switched without using a hot and a separate switch circuit.  I will not explain in detail, cause I feel you really don't have the concept of how this can happen. Sorry if I sound rude.  If you do not have a basic understanding of electrical circuits, than I really recommend you get an electrician to help you. Electrical is not a DIY unless you really know what you are doing. It certainly can be done with some wire fishing, possible wall opening, and some refinishing work after. Be safe and get someone to look at your situation. We cannot tutor you enough here to assure a safe modification you want to do.